# Entity Framework error using select NotMapped in dynamic calc property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My Entity Class

```
[Table("Produtos")]
    public class Produto
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(0, 999.99)]
        public decimal Valor { get; set; }

        public bool Promocao { get; set; }

        public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }

        public virtual Vendedor Vendedor { get; set; }

        public DateTime PromocaoAte { get; set; }

        [Range(0, 999.99)]
        public decimal ValorPromocao { get; set; }

        public bool Excluido { get; set; }

        public decimal valorCompra { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<VendaItem> VendaItems { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Estoques> EstoqueItems { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CarrinhoItem> CarrinhoItems { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int Estoque {
            get {
                return EstoqueItems.Select(i => i.Qtd).Sum(i => i) - VendaItems.Select(i => i.Qtd).Sum(i => i) - CarrinhoItems.Select(i => i.Qtd).Sum(i => i);
            }
            private set { }
        }
    }
```

My Select

```
ctx.Produtos.Select(
           a => new dados_produto
                {
                   nome = a.Nome,
                   id = a.id,
                   valor = a.Valor,
                   estoque = a.Estoque
                }).ToList()
```

Generated Error

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
> EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The specified type member 'Estoque' is not
> supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and
> entity navigation properties are supported.

I've tried several ways to do this, I need this column called Estoque to generate this value dynamically.

Comment: EF is trying to convert your Linq into SQL statements and since the `Estoque` property is not mapped, it doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: Is there a way to create this attribute? or invoke a function that returns the calculation? Alias ​​I already tried to use a function too but returned the same error, I need it to be that way because this attribute cannot be static, and will be used in several parts of the code

Comment: Put the whole code you have in the property, inside the Linq query.